# arrange a data frame by sorting a column within two groups in R and number ir

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R,which I want to arrange and generate sequence column

```
bay    row    tier     flag    
43     11      88       NA
43     11      90       NA
43     11      86       NA
43      9      88       NA
43      9      92       NA
13      4      88       89
13      4      90       NA
13      4      94       NA
11      4      88       89
11      7      90       NA
```

I want to arrange column `tier` in descending order grouping by `bay and row`

Dataframe should look like

```
bay   row     tier     flag
43     11      90       NA
43     11      88       NA
43     11      86       NA
43      9      92       NA
43      9      88       NA
13      4      94       NA
13      4      90       NA
13      4      88       89
11      7      90       NA
11      4      88       89
```

Then I want to generate a sequence for this arranged dataframe

```
 bay   row     tier     flag    seq
 43     11      90       NA     1
 43     11      88       NA     2
 43     11      86       NA     3
 43      9      92       NA     4
 43      9      88       NA     5
 13      4      94       NA     6
 13      4      90       NA     7
 13      4      88       89     8
 11      7      90       NA     9
 11      4      88       89     8
```

The only thing I want to check while generating seq is when `flag` is duplicated I want to keep same `sequence number` for both rows otherwise different numbers for `NA` values

`bay,row and tier` is in `integer` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `order` the 'bay', 'row' and 'tier' in descending order, then create a sequence column 'seq', get the index where the 'flag' are duplicated and is not an `NA`, then specifying the `i` as the logical index and grouped by 'flag' we change the 'seq' to the first value of 'seq'

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df1)[order(-bay, -row, -tier)][,  seq := seq_len(.N)]
i1 <- df2[, (duplicated(flag)|duplicated(flag, fromLast = TRUE)) & !is.na(flag)]
df2[i1, seq := seq[1L], .(flag)]
df2
#    bay row tier flag seq
# 1:  43  11   90   NA   1
# 2:  43  11   88   NA   2
# 3:  43  11   86   NA   3
# 4:  43   9   92   NA   4
# 5:  43   9   88   NA   5
# 6:  13   4   94   NA   6
# 7:  13   4   90   NA   7
# 8:  13   4   88   89   8
# 9:  11   7   90   NA   9
#10:  11   4   88   89   8
```

Comment: I don't want sequence to be group by `bay and row`

Comment: I want only `tier` column to be arranged in descending order.

Comment: please check my desired output.

Comment: @Neil you specifically say "grouping by bay and row."

Comment: I want to keep order of `bay and row` same as in question only `tier` has to be arranged in descending order as in desired dataframe.

Comment: @akrun just a one question. how can we then group all duplicate `seq` number one below other. In above case `row number 8 and then row number 10` then row number 9 and so on

Comment: @Neil That is easy, you can just do `df2[order(seq)]`